# Python scraping script doesn't complete when pySimpleGUI window open

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have this script which works perfectly well without PySimpleGUI, but once I add this '*Downloading...*' window it never completes its job - never creates the csv file and the window just stays open indefinitely.

This script imports a list from another python file in the same project. The imported list looks something like:

```
contracts_list_auto = ['aa563d0b-3695-c99c-b404-7be808106e31?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}', 'dd81a50b-2720-7151-bd93-4e1035e84c07?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}', 'fe66703b-0d80-8e5d-6201-41b2e6b389cd?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}']
```

I want the little *Downloading...* window just let the user know that something is happening and they should wait patiently - no other reason. I also added this *Finished downloading...* line to let them know it's time to find their csv file.

Please help identify where the issue is.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math
import time
from myOtherFile import contracts_list_auto
import PySimpleGUI as sg

baseurl = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/'

layout = [
[sg.Text("Downloading items...", size=(90,1), key='-INFO-')],
[sg.Button('Quit', k='-QUIT-')]
]

window = sg.Window('NFZ Contract Scraper - items',layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == '-QUIT-':
        break

    all_data_items = []

    for contract in contracts_list_auto:
        api_url = ''.join([baseurl, contract])

        def main_request(api_url):
            r = requests.get(api_url)
            return r.json()

        def get_pages(response):
            return math.ceil(response['meta']['count'] / 25)

        p_number = main_request(api_url)

        for page in range(1, get_pages(p_number)+1): # <-- increase page numbers here
            data = requests.get(api_url.format(page)).json()
            agreement_code = data['data']['agreement']['id']
            provider_name = data['data']['agreement']['attributes']['provider-name']
            branch = data['data']['agreement']['attributes']['branch']

            for a in data["data"]["plans"]:
                all_data_items.append({'agreement-code': agreement_code, 'branch': branch, 'provider_name': provider_name, **a["attributes"]})

            df = pd.DataFrame(all_data_items)
            df.to_csv('contracts-detail.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)

        window['-INFO-'].update('Finished downloading contract items')
time.sleep(3)
window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that `PySimpleGUI.Window.read()` will wait infinitely for a user input. To avoid this, you can set a timeout after which it will pass to the next iteration of the loop. Also, I used `threading.Thread` to run your download task in a separate instance of Python to avoid the GUI freezing during the download. To demonstrate that the GUI is not frozen, I made a simple text animation that probably could have been made in a more elegant fashion.

Here is the code, hope it helps!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math
import time
contracts_list_auto = ['aa563d0b-3695-c99c-b404-7be808106e31?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}', 'dd81a50b-2720-7151-bd93-4e1035e84c07?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}', 'fe66703b-0d80-8e5d-6201-41b2e6b389cd?format=json&api-version=1.2&limit=25&page={}']
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from threading import Thread


baseurl = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/'

layout = [
[sg.Text("Downloading items", size=(90,1), key='-INFO-')],
[sg.Button('Quit', k='-QUIT-')]
]
def download():
    all_data_items = []

    for contract in contracts_list_auto:
        api_url = ''.join([baseurl, contract])

        def main_request(api_url):
            r = requests.get(api_url)
            return r.json()

        def get_pages(response):
            return math.ceil(response['meta']['count'] / 25)

        p_number = main_request(api_url)

        for page in range(1, get_pages(p_number)+1): # <-- increase page numbers here
            data = requests.get(api_url.format(page)).json()
            agreement_code = data['data']['agreement']['id']
            provider_name = data['data']['agreement']['attributes']['provider-name']
            branch = data['data']['agreement']['attributes']['branch']

            for a in data["data"]["plans"]:
                all_data_items.append({'agreement-code': agreement_code, 'branch': branch, 'provider_name': provider_name, **a["attributes"]})

            df = pd.DataFrame(all_data_items)
            df.to_csv('contracts-detail.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)

downloader = Thread(target=download)
downloader.start()
window = sg.Window('NFZ Contract Scraper - items',layout)
iterations = [True, False, False]
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=200) # timeout is in ms
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == '-QUIT-':
        break

    if not downloader.is_alive():
        window['-INFO-'].update('Finished downloading contract items')
    else:
        if iterations[0]:
            window['-INFO-'].update('Downloading items.')
            iterations[0] = False
            iterations[1] = True
        elif iterations[1]:
            window['-INFO-'].update('Downloading items..')
            iterations[1] = False
            iterations[2] = True
        else:
            window['-INFO-'].update('Downloading items...')
            iterations[2] = False
            iterations[0] = True
window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes perfect sense and works really well - also the text animation :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful ! Good luck out there xD

Comment: There's a new PySimpleGUI feature that's in the GitHub version that may help in these situations.  It's a Timer services API.  There are 3 calls, each are `Window` methods.  `timer_start`, `timer_stop`, `timer_stop_all`.  They help cut down on the need to use a timeout value by generating events to wake up your GUI, rather than polling using a timeout on the read.  They're described in the docs here: https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#timer-api